# Trying to integrate Rate-Widget (Rate-Module) into Status-Block (Statuses/Facebook Style Status)

Tags: rating

With Drupal 7, I am trying to combine the Rate-module and the statuses-module (formerly Facebook Style Status), for my voting widget to show up in status boxes.

At https://drupal.org/node/811742 it explains to implement the hook hook_facebook_status_render_components.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_facebook_status_render_components().
 */
function MYMODULE_facebook_status_render_components($status) {
  //Only show on individual status pages.
  if (arg(0) == 'statuses' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    //Here, the theme function MYMODULE_voting_widget is assumed to take a "type" and "id" parameter, but it may vary.
    return array(
      'MYMODULE' => array(
        'value' => theme('MYMODULE_voting_widget', 'facebook_status', $status->sid),
      ),
    );
  }
}
?>
```

The README from the rate-module however describes to use the following code:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ($node = node_load(arg(1)))) {
  print rate_embed($node, 'NAME');
}
?>
```

So I used this latter code and implemented the hook in the rate-module:

```
<?php
function rate_facebook_status_render_components($status) {
  //Only show on individual status pages.
  if (arg(0) == 'statuses' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ($node = node_load(arg(1))) ) {
    //Here, the theme function MYMODULE_voting_widget is assumed to take a "type" and "id" parameter, but it may vary.
    print rate_embed($node, 'ratingwidget');
  }
}
?>
```

I deactivated the module and re-activated it, but nothing shows up.
What did I do wrong? Do I need to include any files from the Statuses-module in my rate.info-file, in order to implement hooks from one module in the other? Did I do something totally wrong and just don't understand the concepts?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems here.

I assume you are using Drupal 7, and therefor this module:
https://drupal.org/project/statuses

Which is the successor of facebook_status module for D6.

Your hook is for the D6 module, and does nothing for the D7 module.

I couldn't find the replacement hook in the new D7 version:
http://drupalcode.org/project/statuses.git/blob/bc7e520:/api.php

The other problem, is that 'statuses' are their own 'entity' - for lack of a better word.  They are not actually even 'entities' in the Drupal terminology.  Just some entries in it's own DB table.

The reason this is a problem, is your code is looking to load a node from path when on a path like (/statuses/5), but a 'status' is not a node.

As far as a solution, you'll have to decide a new road to go down, but at least this helps you understand the situation.